# Place a button on Custom view in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm implementing ads through admob in my app. I have a bannerView. I want to place a cancel button on its top right. I have done some code for it but my button is not showing on it.This is my code,

```
UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
float X_Co = bannerView_.frame.size.width - 200;
[but setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, 0.0, 150, 50)];
//[but setFrame:CGRectMake(52, 252, 215, 40)];
[but setTitle:@"CANCEL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[but setExclusiveTouch:YES];
[bannerView_ addSubview:but];


//Admob Banner
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 450, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 70)];
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"; //change this key
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
//request.testDevices = @[ @"326e918015806f8d65a43e86f9e6e939" ];
request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
NSLog(@"%@", request.testDevices);
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
bannerView_.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

How can i show the button on this banner?

Comment: You could use autolayout to position the button.

Comment: I'm want programtically to place it. @Koen

Comment: You can use autolayout in code, it's not only in storyboards.  Did you check the rects of both the banner and button and make sure these are correct?

Comment: For using autolayout, I highly recommend https://cocoapods.org/pods/PureLayout

Makes it super simple to position objects where you want them.

Comment: I would also add a view into self.view which contains the banner, and then add the button into that view instead of into the bannerView.

[container addSubview:bannerView]; [container addSubview: button]; [button autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeTop ofView:bannerView];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the button as a subview to the `bannerView_` before it is even initialised. Change your code to the following and see.

```
//Admob Banner
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 450, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 70)];

// Add the button as subview after you have initialised the bannerView
UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
float X_Co = bannerView_.frame.size.width - 200;
[but setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, 0.0, 150, 50)];
[but setTitle:@"CANCEL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[but setExclusiveTouch:YES];
[bannerView_ addSubview:but];

bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"; //change this key
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
//request.testDevices = @[ @"326e918015806f8d65a43e86f9e6e939" ];
request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
NSLog(@"%@", request.testDevices);
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
bannerView_.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method on you view.

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
```